# Игнорирует условия

Tags: аутентификация, php, mysql

Привет всем.
Игнорируются условия кроме условия HEADER  (внизу) Имя пользователя и пароль уже имеются в базе!

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if(!$db_server) die("Невозможно подключиться к mysql: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Невозможно выбрать базу данных: " . mysql_error());
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    $un_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $pw_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un_temp'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) die ("Сбой при доступе к базе данных: " . mysql_error());
    elseif (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $salt1 = "qm&h*";
        $salt2 = "pg!@";
        $token = md5("$salt1$pw_temp$salt2");

        if ($token == $row[3]) echo "$row[0] $row[1] : Hi, $row[0], now you are registred in name '$row[2]'";
        else die("Неверная комбинация имя пользователя-пароль");
    } else die("Невреная комбинация имя пользователя -пароль");
} else {
    header('WWW-Aithenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
    header('HTTP/1.0401 Unauthorized');
    die ("Please, enter username and password");    
}

function mysql_entities_fix_string($string) {
    return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($string));
}

function mysql_fix_string($string) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
    return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}
?>
```

Comment: Не выполняется условие  

    isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])

Научитесь форматировать код отступами - когда будете читать свой код через месяц сами себе спасибо скажете.

Comment: вместе с функционалом stackoverflow.com имеете и косяки теже

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, соединяется ли PHP с БД (отправьте простой запрос). Если да, то следующие условие не исполняется и нужно устанить проблему:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
```